# How to schedule sql scripts to executed at regular intervals on prod DB servers

Tags: mysql, database, validation, monitoring

I am building a Data monitoring system to catch data issues on prod DB. I have written some SQL scripts with all validation and the script returns data which fails the validations.

1. Is there any free to tool to do this or is there a better way to achieve this?
2. How can I schedule my SQL scripts to run on regular intervals from one of our servers?

Comment: Pls do not ask us to recommend you a tool because such questions are explicitly off topic here.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on linux based systems, you can use [cron](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/).